# Objective-C facebook API

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, facebook

Can someone point me to Objective-C facebook API. I need to use it for iOS SDK 4.2. I have found twitter API but not face book. Please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know what you're trying to do, but if you're simply trying to share something on Facebook, ShareKit should make things very simple: http://www.getsharekit.com/

Otherwise, you'll have to use the iOS SDK, which allows for more functionality but also involves writing more code: http://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

Answer (score 4):

You can use the sdk from Facebook on github:

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

Answer (score 1):

Why no body points at the obvious one true source of Facebook for IOS API

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios